# how to check invite url after app first time install

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am building social media app using flutter.
user1 sends a app link through sms or other platform, user2 open that link and install the app from play store/app store depending on platform. Is there a way to check url after user2 install and open the app for the first time? so that app can verify the referred by without user2 enter referral code manually and it should work for both Android and iOS

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for that there is Firebase deep links that you can read the documentation of [here](https://firebase.google.com/products/dynamic-links?gclid=CjwKCAiAx8KQBhAGEiwAD3EiP4OSucjYbXHKnkA3jJirbgfdwN4lYIvIORFv7x575yb_1fr7mTJy1BoCyiwQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds).

They are basically deep links that "survive the app installation process" as it is officially documented.

Comment: is there way to achieve this without Firebase?

Comment: Yes but you will need a custom solution. What Firebase is perhaps doing is that it's storing some additional information in form of a cookie on the iOS host platform when a link is tapped before it redirects the user to the App Store. Then upon the app opening, it tries to read the cookie and retrieves the information. So you could potentially implement this yourself.

Comment: I tried that but not able read cookie inside the app that set on browser(from server). I used this [webview_cookie_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_cookie_manager) package to read browser cookie